# Remove letters from cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row of cells containing both text and numbers. I would like to AUTOMATICALLY create a row beneath it containing only the numbers and decimal point.

[image]

Is this possible with Office 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell A2 (assuming first value is in cell A1):

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",2))-(FIND(" ",A1)+1)))
```

Now copy over.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),LEN(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))-1)
```

An alternative to cover `mg` and `mmg` as well as `g`:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))))
```

Preserves the decimal point in `Orange 1.0 g` but does so by leaving the result as text format.

Comment: Thanks. This works for g but not mg. For mg, Almonds 1.9999 mg becomes 1.9999 m. Can you make it work for g mg or mmg?